# Trying to creat a while loop for this kind of statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am a newbie to python, i am working on trying to see how I can rewrite a code that is trying to wait on 2 different variables I believe, this is what I have so far.

```
def generate_random():
    number = random.randint(1,10)
    return number

def main() :
        guessed_number = int(input("Please select a number between 1 and 10 "))
        if guessed_number > 1 and guessed_number <= 10:
            random_number = generate_random()
            if guessed_number == random_number:
                print("Successful guess!")
            else:
                 print("Unsuccessful guess")
        else:
             print("You need to choose a number between 1 and 10")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I haven't really tried much in trying to fix it, just curious which directions i can go

Comment: Please update your question with the formatted *text* of your code.

Comment: Don't post links to images because we can't copy/paste/adujst it. Actually paste the code and enclose it in the code markers (use the "formatting help" to do this. I've edited the question for you, but remember this in future

Comment: Should the while loop act as a way to verify you correctly guessed? E.g. loop until you get the right number, then quit?

Comment: #B Remmelzwaal, technically that is one half of what i was looking for, my teacher basically said that the if/and statement of the >1 and <10 could be changed into a while loop, he just couldnt remember how. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I really didn't know what you are looking for. So I hope you don't mind if I fixed your code and added my own flair in the process:

```
import random

def generate_random():
    number = random.randint(1,10)
    return number

def main() :
    correctValue = False
    random_number = generate_random()


    while correctValue != True:
        guessed_number = int(input("Please select a number (1 - 10): "))
        if guessed_number >= 1 and guessed_number <= 10:
            if guessed_number == random_number:
                print("Successful guess!")
                correctValue = True
            elif guessed_number < random_number:
                print("Smaller then guessed number")
            elif guessed_number > random_number:
                print("Larger then guessed number")
            else:
                 print("Unsuccessful guess")
        else:
             print("You need to choose a number between 1 and 10")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Would recommend you use my code above, dissect it and compare it to what you had.  Dissecting working code is a great way to learn.

Comment: This one is nice, when ran, it has a issue in there where even if you select the number 1 it says "Larger then guessed number

Comment: I found out what was going on, You had the > and < signs reversed in the elif statement, i fixed it and its working wonderfully

Comment: Glad it helps.  Finding and solving bugs is another great way to learn :P

Comment: For sure! i showed it to my class as an example, they all loved it!

Comment: Upvote would be appreciated then :)

Answer (score -2):

Did you mean that you want to loop over the whole program?

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        main()
```

Comment: Maybe, i believe what I was trying to accomplish is changing the whole thing where  if guessed_number > 1 and guessed_number <= 10: could be converted into a while loop instead of a if/and

Comment: So the code I posted does that. Did you want something different?

Comment: nope. sorry like said, im going through school for python.

Comment: I'm asking how the code I posted does not perform the behaviour you are after.

Comment: Terribly sorry, im not too sure how to elaborate on what i am looking for, my teacher stated there is a way to turn the if/and statement of the code into a while loop instead. I appreciate the responses you did give, it showed me something new.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) help at all?

Comment: Yes helps alot into what i am trying to do, now to just implement that method of the while True: into my code. Thanks!